# React-native android stickyHeader

Tags: listview, scrollview, react-native

I want to implement sticky header in android. I tried to write a custom view using panResponder, but the scroll is very jerky in that. I also tried to use a scrollview and a list view, but I was unable to pass the control from scrollView to listView and vice-versa. Please, suggest a way to achieve this in react-native android. I have posted the code here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523007/react-native-android-nested-scrollview-and-listview-not-passing-control-to-each

Comment: Do you find a way to implement it?